# Merging multiple PHP arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, merge

My problem is this: I'm creating an Array in order to store these 2 types of 'refinement'. However, what is happening is as the information is collected from the database, each 'refinement' is assigned to it's own specific entry when the arrays are created within the while loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
etc...
}
```

So for instance, the 1st array would be a reference to 'Die Hard' and the 2nd, 'Breaking Bad' and the 3rd, 'Greys Anatomy'. What i'm trying to achieve is to merge them into 1 single array.

```
Array 
      ( 
      [genreType] => Action
      [mediaType] => Film
      ) 

Array 
      ( 
      [genreType] => Action
      [mediaType] => TV
      )  

Array 
      ( 
      [genreType] => Drama
      [mediaType] => TV
      )
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried creating a temp variable array outside of the loop and then using the loop to append the values into the array?

Comment: So you are trying to make something like this: `Array([genretype1]=>Action [mediatype1]=>Film [genretype2]=>Action` etc?

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at this, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
<?php
    $array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
    $array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
    $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array (
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just use `array_merge`? from the php docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

```
while{$row...
{
    $movies[] = $row;
    //OR
    $tmp['genreType'] = $row['genre'];
    //and the like.....
    $movies[] = $tmp;
}
```

Resulting in

```
$movies = array(
             array(
               "title"=>"Die Hard", 
               "genreType"=>"Action", 
               "mediaType"=>"Film"
             ),
             array(
               "title"=>"some other movie",
               "genreType"=>"Comedy",
               "mediaType"=>"TV"
             )
           );
```

like this?